# Circuit to charge battery from solar panel

Tags: switches, battery-charging, solar-energy

If I want to charge a battery from a solar panel without using a commercial charger, then the essential problem is to create two voltage-triggered switches. One switch turns current on when the voltage in the battery drops below a certain threshold and the other disconnects the panel when the voltage rises to the "full"/higher threshold.

One advantage of having a system like this is that I can select the threshold voltages, instead of the charger guessing what might be optimal.

What would be the right kind of circuit to solve this problem? Ideally, I would like a system that requires no power to operate, at least when it is charging, because I want the energy to be used to charge the battery, not run the circuit.

Comment: The term you're looking for is "energy harvesting".

Comment: Maximum power point tracking

Comment: What kind of batteries are you charging?

Comment: It seems to me that the problem is a bit more complicated than you appreciate. Also, good chargers don't "guess" what the optimal charge voltage should be. Good chargers are optimized to the specific battery chemistry and temperature to charge them quickly and without damaging the batteries.

Comment: At this point I just want an answer to my question, which is how to make a circuit with the two switches described.

Comment: Would it kill you to say what kind of batteries you are charging? I asked for a reason. If  you just want to know what type of circuit, well, it is the kind with a voltage reference, a comparator, and a PMOS. You don't need to shunt the panel to ground. What is the point of that? Just put PMOS between battery and panel, and turn off PMOS when you don't want to charge. But there are a lot of pitfalls that you seem uninterested in.

Comment: "One switch turns current on when the voltage in the battery drops below a certain threshold" - what do you want to happen when the battery is _above_ the certain threshold?

Comment: @BruceAbbott I answered that in the question.

Comment: After your edit it now seems clear that you actually only want _one_ switch, which turns charging current on at the lower threshold and turns it off at the higher threshold - right?

Comment: @BruceAbbott No, you (probably) need two switches. So, for example, if the low voltage is 11.8 V and the high voltage is 12.7 volts, then the charging needs to be turned on when voltage goes down to 11.8V, then it keeps charging until it reaches 12.7 V, then it turns off. There are four possible states: (1) below 11.8 (2) above 12.7 (3) between 11.8 and 12.7 and charging, (4) between 11.8 and 12.7 and not charging. Since there are four possible states you need 2 two-way switches, or one four-way switch.

Comment: No, you only need _one_ switch that waits until the voltage goes down to 11.8V, then turns on until until it reaches 12.7V, then turns off again. A _single_ switch, with **hysteresis**. 11.8V, 12.7V - what type of battery is this?

Answer (score 1):

This disadvantage of this method is the loss of energy if the PV ope circuit is more than 18V due to impedance mismatch or lack of Maximum Power Transfer or PMT which runs approx  80% of Voc.

But this is basically how a car alternator works with lots of power and inefficiency behind it.

YOu can choose a high side Logic switch for automotive high switched currents and logic level input from a comparator with a precision reference voltage to scale 14.2 down to the reference voltage, assuming lead acid battery.

If that is of interest, I or someone can show you this inefficient method.

Ideally you want the battery voltage to be 80% of the open circuit voltage or Voc.

**This will explain why a 42% improvement is possible with PMMT.**
[image]

ref www.roguepowertech.com/documents/MPT3048Rev2-Manual.pdf

Comment: You have to have a lot of hysteresis or a time delay. Otherwise the FET may turn on and off rapidly during some conditions, and cause the FET to essentially go into the linear region. This could lead to excessive dissipation. This is one of the pitfalls. If the panel is well matched to the battery (which the OP still has not identified) it can be a decent way to go. The inefficiency is not that bad.

Comment: good point, you can add 1~3% positive feedback with a delay cap and you need a Schottky diode to prevent reverse drain

Comment: then one can add an Imax current rated choke and call it a DC-DC converter with 10kF battery and small plastic cap added for improved efficiency..